# Golang Virtual File

Tags: hadoop, go, named-pipes, fuse

I have a closed soruce application that takes a file as an input, calculates its hash and does some other stuff I have no control. Modifiying source or reverse engineering is not feasible.

The program is designed to work with regular files, however I need to supply a very large file from HDFS. Copying the file will take too much time and space on disk. So I was thinking of using FUSE but I did not find a good solution. I tried using a named pipe as follows:

```
func readFile(namenode, path string, pipe *os.File) {
    client, err := hdfs.New(namenode)
    log.Println(err, client)

    hdfsFile, err := client.Open(path)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    log.Println(hdfsFile)

    // written, err := io.Copy(pipe, hdfsFile)
    bytes := make([]byte, 4096)
    for {
        read, err := hdfsFile.Read(bytes)
        log.Println(read, err)
        if err != nil {
            break
        }
        written, err := pipe.Write(bytes)
        log.Println(written, err)
    }
    err = pipe.Close()
    log.Println(err)
}
```

I know the above code is not complete, the test file is 10MB, however after reading 8 times 4096 bytes named pipe buffer gets full and the other program takes it all and closes the pipe.

But after a while the other program that is reading the pipe closes the pipe and I get broken pipe error. Is there any possibility of creating a virtual file other than fuse and pipe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you actually had the right idea with FUSE.  Without sources for your upstream application, it's hard to say what file semantics it's trying to use (though some time with strace might help to illuminate what's going on.  Maybe...).

In any case, I'd have a look at [the Go-FUSE project](https://github.com/hanwen/go-fuse), specifically [the hello.go example](https://github.com/hanwen/go-fuse/tree/master/example/hello), which shows exactly how to handle the single file case very well.

Answer (score 1):

I understand the problem is that the closed source program2 expects a file name and does not accept input directly from *stdin*?

You can use a standard Unix-style pipeline when running the programs to connect the *stdin* and *stdout* of the processes together. Named pipes can be problematic and using FUSE for this is overly complicated.

You could make your program1 to output to *stdout*. and supply the closed source program2 with the virtual file name `/dev/stdin` as follows:

```
program1 | program2 /dev/stdin
```

This is assuming you are working on Linux (you did not specify but I assume so because you are talking about FUSE).

If program2 cares about the file name (expects a specific name extension for example), you might be able to work around that by creating a symbolic link with the desired name pointing to `/dev/stdin` and supplying the name of the symbolic link as the argument to program2:

```
ln -s /dev/stdin file.ext
program1 | program2 file.ext
rm -f file.ext
```

None of this will work if program2 expects a real file which it can *stat*   but in this case that should not be an issue (as it is known from the question that program2 accepts a named pipe).

Also if program2 expects keyboard input from *stdin* this approach will not work.